# crash in app, after iAd id added

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, iad

I have added iAd to my app. Its running fine but when that ViewController is dismissed then app crashes.
iAd and delegate object is set to nil(after we dismiss controller) so no problem from here.

I am adding iad like this with all delegate methods implemented

```
self.adBannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
self.adBannerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 710, 1024, 66);
self.adBannerView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:adBannerView];
```

I am getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS at line

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate");
```

Comment: At first you can replace 2 first lines with one: `self.adBannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 710, 1024, 66)]`. And you should give us some crash logs.

Comment: Tom is right, but for what reason you are using retVal?

Comment: I am not using. Its default code in AppDelegate file.

Comment: Please add breakpoint on Exception Thrown. Then you may see some more interesting error log. Go to `Breakpoint Navigator > Plus/Add > Add Exception Breakpoint`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include the iAdFramework and AdSupportFrameworks..

Goto your Targets > Buildphases > Link Binary with Libraries